# How to get Telegram user profile photo by user ID with aiogram v2?

Tags: python, aiogram

I trying to get Telegram user profile photo by user ID with aiogram v2.

```
def get_photo(user_id):
    photo_data = bot.get_user_profile_photos(user_id, 1, 1)
    return photo_data

@dp.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
async def get_user_photo():
    photo_data = get_photo(367928353)
    #logger.error(photo_data)
    await message.answer(photo_data)
```

by command '/photo' I receive:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-8' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /home/r/rlyzhov/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:407> exception=TypeError('get_user_photo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/r/rlyzhov/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "/home/r/rlyzhov/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/home/r/rlyzhov/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/home/r/rlyzhov/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "/home/r/rlyzhov/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
TypeError: get_user_photo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

What I do wrong?

I understand last TypeError, but what and where I give it 1 argument?
Perhaps my knowlege of aiogram and async functions are too small yet

Please tell me what I need to read to understand the problem and solve it.
Thank you

try: get Telegram user profile photo by user ID with aiogram v2
expect: Telegram user photo
recieve: error

Comment: Please read the description of tags before using it. The python-telegram-bot tag is not a general tag about telegram bots written in python

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need read the documentation, namely about handlers. Just your function `get_phot` is synchronous which used asynchronous method `bot.get_user_profile_photos` after then you create a handlers `get_user_photo()` but don't transmit parameters `types.Message` from aiogram.  I rewrote your code and that's what came out.

```py
from aiogram import types
from loader import dp


@dp.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
async def get_user_photo(message: types.Message):
    profile_pictures = await dp.bot.get_user_profile_photos(message.from_user.id)
    await message.answer_photo(dict((profile_pictures.photos[0][0])).get("file_id"))
```

For this task i think we don't need create another function, but if you want you can create. In `profile_pictures` we saved `PhotoSize` which store all information about user profile photo. In the next line we convert `PhotoSize` in `dict and we take only the "file_id". For the test, we send this photo to the chat